# How to hide context menu item when mouse out on grid

Tags: vb.net, winforms, infragistics

I am using windows forms with vb.net. This form has infragistics ultra win grid. with context menu item. The item name is "Delete Item". But when the user performs mouse out from grid i want to hide context menu item and when user hover back to the grid i want to show the context menu item. How can i do this.

[image]

Comment: You want a context menu item to just float in space, with no tie to the mouse pointer?  Or a right-click?  Why not just a button you show/hide?  Seems like an odd way to go about it...

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) write code to handle the 'BeforeToolDropdown' event

example method signature:

```
    Private Sub ultraToolbar_BeforeToolDropdown(sender As Object, e As
       BeforeToolDropdownEventArgs) Handles ultraToolbar.BeforeToolDropdown
```

Step 2) this gets you a very important **e**ventArgs object.  Check to see if the click occurred in the  Ultragrid

```
    If IsNothing(TryCast(e.SourceControl, UltraGrid)) Then
```

Step 3) Finally you want to disable the PopupMenuTool

```
    Dim p As PopupMenuTool = CType(utb.Tools("key"), PopupMenuTool)
    p.InstanceProps.Visible = DefaultableBoolean.False
```

Note: in the example, the PopupMenuTool was located on an UltraToolbarsManager